# How to append multiple tags & script using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm very new to JQuery and have what is probably a very basic query.

I am trying to append a series of tags including a script into a DIV with a ID, I keep on getting the error:

'Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL'

this is the script:

```
<script>
 $("#addBender").click(function() {
  alert("Handler for .click() called.");
  $(".addBender").append('<pre class="_cssdeck_embed" data-pane="output" data-user="devilsbackyard" data-href="dancing-robot-with-reflection" data-version="0"></pre>\<script async src="http://cssdeck.com/assets/js/embed.js"></script>');
 });
</script>
```

The HTML click element (#bender) and DIV (class="addBender") to append to.....

```
<div class="gradientbuttons" id="addBender" class="clickSlide">
    <ul class="redtheme">
       <li><a href="#">Sad man walks slowly</a></li>
    </ul> 
</div>

<!--add bender here when button clicked-->
<div class="addBender"></div>
```

Comment: if addBender is ID then $('#addBender').append() is the syntax. try adding your code to fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$("#addBender").click(function() {
 alert("Handler for .click() called.");
 $(".addBender").append('<pre class="_cssdeck_embed" data-pane="output" data-user="devilsbackyard" data-href="dancing-robot-with-reflection" data-version="0"><'+'/'+'pre><script async src="http://cssdeck.com/assets/js/embed.js"><'+'/'+'script>');
});
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/subins2000/tVgT6/2)

Comment: Ill try that. But what's JFiddle??

Comment: @dancingbush It's a site for online demos (html,css,js,jquery). http://jsfiddle.net